# Detecting Enemies inside Area,Detecting Enemies inside Circle UNITY2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im doing my first game and im trying to detect the enemies inside an circle area around my player.

i have two problems right now:

-When a start the game, the circlecollider and player collider is detected as enemies even when i use the compare tag "Enemy"

-My corroutine dont refresh every 2s, and only detect colliders one time when the game start

```
public class ItemDamage : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [SerializeField] int damage;
     [SerializeField] Collider2D[] objectsInsideArea;
     Vector2 radiusOfDamage;
     int radius;
     public void Start()
     {
         radiusOfDamage = new Vector2(radius, 0f);
         StartCoroutine(DamageEnemy());
     }
  
     bool IsEnemy(string tag)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < objectsInsideArea.Length; i++)
             if (objectsInsideArea[i].gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
             {
                 Debug.Log("object {i} is an Enemy");
                 return true;
             } else
             {
                 Debug.Log("object {i}");
             }
         return false;
     }
  
     IEnumerator DamageEnemy()
     {
         objectsInsideArea = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(Vector2.zero, radiusOfDamage);
         foreach (bool IsEnemy in objectsInsideArea)
         {
             Debug.Log("You damage the enemy");
         }
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don’t understand how this code is able to compile? `objectsInsideArea` is not an array of bools so I’d expect `foreach(bool x in objectsInsideArea)` to fail with “`Cannot convert type 'Collider2D' to 'bool'`”?

Answer (score 1):

For coroutine to repeat itself, it has to start itself in the end again like this:

```
IEnumerator DamageEnemy()
     {
         objectsInsideArea = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(Vector2.zero, radiusOfDamage);
         foreach (bool IsEnemy in objectsInsideArea)
         {
             Debug.Log("You damage the enemy");
         }
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
         StartCoroutine(DamageEnemy());
     }
```

Also instead of coroutine for this, you can use [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) method.

You don't have to use a predefined array of objects, but rather use [SphereRaycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) method where you specify layer of objects to look for.
And your enemies can be located in the specific [layer](https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/58894-unity-layers-ui-toggle.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

A Caroutine does not start it self.

For the other problem. `objectsInsideArea` is a Collider array and not a bool array. You cannot check it this way. Your code must look like this:

```cs
IEnumerator DamageEnemy()
{
     while(someBoolOrTrue) {
          objectsInsideArea = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(Vector2.zero, radiusOfDamage);
          foreach (var collider in objectsInsideArea)
          {
               if(collider.tag.Equals("Enemy")) {
                    Debug.Log("You damage the enemy");
               }
          }
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }

}
```